# Delegate pattern vs delegate keyword in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, delegates

From [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx):

> A delegate is a type that safely encapsulates a method, similar to a
>   function pointer in C and C++. Unlike C function pointers, delegates
>   are object-oriented, type safe, and secure.

I know what it is and how to use it. But I wonder whether or not it is written base on delegate pattern that I know (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)) .
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# (not the pattern) delegate might be useful when you are implementing the [delegate pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) just look at this delegate pattern implementation from wikipedia with my changes:

```
//NOTE: this is just a sample, not a suggestion to do it in such way

public interface I
{
    void F();
    void G();
}

public static class A
{
    public static void F() { System.Console.WriteLine("A: doing F()"); }
    public static void G() { System.Console.WriteLine("A: doing G()"); }
}

public static class B
{
    public static void F() { System.Console.WriteLine("B: doing F()"); }
    public static void G() { System.Console.WriteLine("B: doing G()"); }
}

public class C : I
{
    // delegation 
    Action iF = A.F;
    Action iG = A.G;

    public void F() { iF(); }
    public void G() { iG(); }

    // normal attributes
    public void ToA() { iF = A.F; iG = A.G; }
    public void ToB() { iF = B.F; iG = B.G; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.F();     // output: A: doing F()
        c.G();     // output: A: doing G()
        c.ToB();
        c.F();     // output: B: doing F()
        c.G();     // output: B: doing G()
    }
}
```

Again delegate *might* be useful here, but it isn't for it was introduced. You should look at it like on the low-level construction rather then the pattern. In the pair with the [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it could be used to implement [publisher/subscriber(observer) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) - just look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx), or it could sometimes help you to implement [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) - this is actively used in the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb397926%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public void Linq1() 
{ 
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 

    // n => n < 5 is lambda function, creates a delegate here
    var lowNums = numbers.Where(n => n < 5); 

    Console.WriteLine("Numbers < 5:"); 
    foreach (var x in lowNums) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(x); 
    } 
}
```

**To summarize:** a language delegate is not the pattern itself, it just allows you to operate functions as the [first class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Answer (score 2):

The [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) is:

> a design pattern [...] where an object, instead of performing one of its stated tasks, delegates that task to an associated helper object.

Unfortunately, that page does not describe much about when to use it or what patterns derive from it, apart from

> The delegation pattern is one of the fundamental abstraction patterns that underlie other software patterns such as composition (also referred to as aggregation), mixins and aspects.

From the page that [describes delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29), you can figure that it is to delegate the implementation of a feature to a class that may or may not be known at runtime. When you say `Foo.Bar()`, the implementation of that may *delegate* the execution of `Bar()` to the beforementioned "helper object".

Now for the C# delegate, as stated, that's simply a function pointer. It can help implement a delegation pattern, by assigning the delegation method at either compile time or runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The *delegation pattern* is a way for an object to delegate responsibility for a task to an external method. It uses a *delegate* to keep track of that method. So one use for a *delegate* is to implement the *delegation pattern*.

The pattern is used for example in the `List<T>.Sort(comparison)` method, where the sorting algorithm uses a delegate that you provide it with to compare items.